# gdal's polygonize function (via qgis) is not turning monochrome rasters into readable shapefiles regardless of inversion of color scale

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, polygonize

I've tried polygonizing this monochrome bitmap as this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

and either way it ends up looking like this when (zoomed in) after gdal's polygonize operation:

[image]

Is there any way I can tell it which binary component I want to be the shape and which I want to be the void?

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-band raster (not RGB) having pixels with values of 0 and 255, yes? Perhaps the raster would benefit from a little pre-processing, you might like to try Raster | Analysis | Sieve before using the raster polygoniser. You might also have to experiment with the sieve settings. The polygoniser doesn't know anything about colours, only about pixel values, by the way.

Comment: What *does* the polygonizer use to interpret polygons? Its looking like a combination of the alpha layer with something else

Comment: It uses pixel values, the raster polygonizer makes polygons that enclose groups of pixels of the same value. This is why it is sometimes important to sieve out small clumps of pixels before running the polygonizer or you can end up with huge number of tiny polygons. Which I think is what you have.

Comment: sieve helps a lot. another tool I used was gimp's Threshold Alpha in the Layers menu

Comment: I think this question unfocused however, having solved this problem I think this question, at best, is a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84002/low-resolution-raster-conversions-to-vector-yielding-millions-of-single-pixel-po -- flagging for removal